# How to modify a property of a received WPF routed event arg parameter before resuming its propagation?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls

I'm playing with a custom TextBox inheriting from the WPF TextBox, trying to learn about WPF events, so my problem is the following: **When the TextBox receives an input, I want it to receive instead a case inverted version of this input**. For example, if I type on the key (lowercase) "a", I want the TextBox to print a (uppercase) "A" instead of (lowercase) "a".

My (partial) solution is, in my custom TextBox, to intercept the TextInput event by overloading the method [`OnPreviewTextInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.onpreviewtextinput.aspx). When this method is called, I receive a [`TextCompositionEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.textcompositioneventargs.aspx)  whose [`Text`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.textcompositioneventargs.text.aspx) property is "a".

So my first reflex would be updating this Text property to "A", as in the following code:

```
protected override void OnPreviewTextInput(TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
   e.Text = "A" ;
   base.OnPreviewTextInput(e) ;
}
```

The problem is that e.Text is readonly, and that I found no easy way to do that (and I searched, and I tweaked both the [`TextComposition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.textcomposition.aspx) and [`TextCompositionEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.textcompositioneventargs.aspx), trying to construct one from zero, copying the data, etc.).

Did I miss something obvious?
Is there a way to do it?

*P.S.: The other solution was to use the WPF TextBox interface to tweak the result (retrieving the current .Text property, putting the inverted character inside, etc.), but this is not the desired solution as it bypasses completely the routed event generation/modification problem I'm trying to solve)*

Comment: Yes e is read only. And Key.A is is a little clean syntax.  Look at overriding.

Comment: @BalamBalam: Not exactly, `e.Text` is readonly (as I wrote in the original question), but `e` is not (as `e.Handled` can be modified)... Thanks for the input, though... ^_^ ... And what do you mean by "And Key.A is is a little clean syntax"? And by "Look at overriding"? Your comment is confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change the event data. The events are there to notify you that something has happened or is happening and possibly let you cancel/handle it.

In you case the best you can do is mark the event as [Handled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.routedeventargs.handled.aspx) and then append the Text to the textbox yourself.

If you just need the uppercase scenario you can use the [CharacterCasing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.charactercasing.aspx) property which does just that.

Comment: As I wrote in the original question's P.S., I already tried the workarounds, but in some cases (applying the same feature to a ComboBox, for example), this is not possible. Intercepting the original and sending a new event seems the best solution, but I see in debug that some private fields are not set the same way in the original event and my own (the bitvector, invoking handler, the stage, etc.).

Comment: The routed event system hasn't been designed with what your are suggesting in mind so its next to impossible to use it in that way - modifying values on the fly.

Comment: Accepted answer: This answer is quite unfortunate (from my viewpoint), but then, one must do what as much as possible with what is available... ^_^ ... In my case, I had to intercept the event (and mark it handled before calling the base method), and in the cases I wanted to handle, reproduce the desired effects "by hand" (including selection of part of the text), which is a pain (and a maintenance nightmare).